# How can I add Y-axis/Pitch/Vertical to LineTraceByChannel Raycast with Unreal Blueprints?

Tags: raycasting, unreal, blueprints

I am using LineTraceByChannel to cast a ray and return the name of the object it hits in my game world. It works but I am having trouble working out how to add the Y-axis (Up/Down) value. At the moment the ray is only cast horizontal to the ground, regardless of whether the player is looking up or down.

I tried adding a Pitch variable and getting the y-axis value but haven't worked out how exactly to use this. I followed a tutorial to get this far so any further advice is much appreciated.

This is my blueprint currently

[image]

The 'Selection Beam' component is attached to the character mesh, facing forwards:

[image]

This is where I get the input from the Mouse Y axis, if that helps:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Double-click your character to edit it. Look at the details panel on the right. Check the box next to 'Use Controller Rotation Pitch'. Thats it, simple!

[image]